# PHP generate Excel/CSV file and send as UTF-8

Tags: php

I'm retrieving data from my Postgres DB in UTF-8. The db and the client_connection settings are in UTF-8.

Then I send 2 headers to the visitor:

```
header("Content-Type: application/msexcel");
header("Content-Disposition: $mode; filename=export.xls");
```

and start outputting plain text data in a CSV-manner. This will open as a simple Excel file on the visitors desktop.

```
$cols = array ("col1", "col2", "col3");
echo implode("\t", $cols)."\r\n";
```

Works fine, untill special characters like é, è etc are encountered.

I tried changing my client_encoding while retrieving the data from the db to latin-1, which works in most cases but not for all chars. So that is not a solution.

How could I send the outputted file as UTF-8? I don't think converting the data from the db to latin-1 is possible, since the char seems unknown in latin-1 ...  so I need Excel to treat the file as UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into using the [PHPExcel engine](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It uses UTF-8 as default and it can generate a whole list of spreadsheet file types (Excel, OpenOffice, CSV, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not sending plain-text and masquerading it as Excel. XLS files are typically binary, and while binary isn't required, the official Excel method of using non-binary data is to format it as [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel_file_format#File_formats).

You mention "CSV" in the title, but nothing about your problem includes anything related to CSV. I bring this up because I believe that you should actually change your tabs to commas, and then you could simply output a standard .csv file, which is read by Excel still but doesn't rely on undocumented or unstable functionality.

If you truly want to send `application/msexcel`, then you should use a real Excel library, because currently, you are **not** creating a real Excel file.

Comment: That's true, and there is a library to deal with Excel files, such as http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/ and infact I'm sure there's probably hundreds out there. There is one native to PHP, however it only runs on Windows servers, I can't remember the name of it though :/

Comment: I know, I'm generating TSV files instead of CSV files, but the result is the same: it's a plain text file with the data seperated by a separator. I'm maskerading as XLS so the visitor's desktop will open the file appropriately instead of in a Txt-editor or something alike. That does work fine, untill your output contains some special characters.

Comment: That is not a valid reason to masquerade as .xls; Excel sets itself as the default application for .csv files.

Answer (score 1):

use ; charset=UTF-8 after aplication/xxxxxx I do use:

```
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
//  header("Content-Length: " . strlen($thecontent));     // this is not mandatory
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php), for converting string into required charset.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function.

Comment: WebFlakeStudio: isn't the other way around possible: send a certain header so Excel will know it's to open the file as UTF-8 ?

Comment: @user410932: No. The file is transferred using HTTP, and then opened through normal means - Excel isn't downloading the file, and the HTTP headers won't be accessible to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried utf8_encode() the string?

So something like: `echo implode("\t", utf8_encode($cols)."\r\n")`

Not sure if that would work, but give it a go

Comment: Unless your trying to encode the entire file which then it wouldn't work